# How to create custom scaffold templates in ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm using ASP.NET MVC5 and VS2013

I've tried to copy CodeTemplates folder from

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpress\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 4\CodeTemplates

with subfolders "AddController", "AddView" and T4 templates inside them, then I modified some templates, but nothing happened when I tried to add View nor Controller..

Comment: I've dug around a bit and haven't found a way to customize the scaffolding system.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, it looks like you have Visual Studio 2013 and 2012 both installed on your computer. I tried looking up the path you provided, I couldn't find it. On your path it looks like you're trying to use MVC4 templates. Here is my path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\
Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates
```

Below is how I customized my scaffold template for the BaseController:

1. Create folder called "CodeTemplates" directly in the project folder.
2. Go to below path, find MvcControllerWithActions folder copy all to folder "CodeTemplates"

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\
   Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates
   ```
3. Go to CodeTemplates -> MvcControllerWithActions in your project.
4. There are two files, `Controller.cs.t4` and `Controller.vb.t4` in MvcControllerWithActions, if you used C#, you can delete `Controller.vb.t4`.
5. Open the `Controller.cs.t4` file, modify the Controller name to BaseController, like below:

   ```
   public class <#= ControllerName #> : BaseController
   {
   }
   ```
6. Now, when you try to create MVC5 Controller using "add new scaffold item", it'll use the template you customized.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it works well! I my case I'm using VSExpress, so actual path is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpressExtensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates

Comment: Funny, mine are located at: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC\1033`

Comment: `1033`? WHy doesn't my folder have `Scaffolding/Templates`? Weird

Comment: Instead of modifying the template, I want to add new template so that I have option to select either default or my customized template depending on the requirement. Is this possible ? I tried to do it my copying the default template in my solution and renaming it. But when I add controller it doesn't show my template there.

Answer (score 3):

MVC4 and MVC5 templates are located in different locations. While MVC4 templates are located in the folder you've given, MVC5 templates are located in this folder:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates**

What you need to do for customizing is to create a folder named `CodeTemplates` your project folder, and copy the templates you want to customize to the `CodeTemplates` folder.

You'll need to copy `MvcView` and `MvcControllerWithContext` folders in order to use with **MVC 5 Controller with view, using EntityFramework** command.

**CAUTION**

- **Both directories must have the same folder structure**. What I mean is, do not copy the `Create.cs.t4` in the `MvcView` folder directly into the `CodeTemplates` folder. Just copy the entire `MvcView` folder into `CodeTemplates` folder.
- **Do not delete include files** such as `Imports.include.t4` and `ModelMetadataFunctions.cs.include.t4` because other files need them to be there.
- If you're using C#, feel free to delete files with `.vb.t4` extension and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

The MVC5 T4 templates are located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\VWDExpressExtensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates\MvcView

Answer (score 2):

In `VS 2015` templates found in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates\MvcView

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2017 MVC5 T4 templates are located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates\MvcView