# Defining CSS style before generating Razor View in MVC

Tags: c#, css, razor, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I've encountered one little annoying problem with MVC that didn't happen with .aspx pages: the style that is being applied when generating a View from a controller.

In .aspx pages, I used a masterpage with contentplaceholders and anything generated just goes like normal, but with Razor the classes, divs, etc. are predefined apperantly even though I have a masterlayout that doesn't have any of those generated classes.

How can I predefine the classes or divs, etc. that need to be generated instead of editing them page by page?

For example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>User</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lastname, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"        })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lastname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lastname)
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see the classes `form-horizontal`, `form-group',`control-md-10`,`control-label`, etc.. are automatically added. Where or how can I customize this?

Comment: the view that you created is just a template the MVC 5 offers to show an example of a clean form generated by a model to do basic CRUD, I think you are looking for new Empty View

Comment: There would be no way for an IDE to just generate views and make div's and inputs and know what classes you would like on everything,  You are going to have to manually format everything.  What you can look into is a partial view for re-usable forms , format and style them there and then use those .

Comment: @ScottSelby Well the IDE (visual studio 2013) adds automaticly those classes, I think based on what kind of CRUD it is. Generating a list has other classes than a create for example. ASPX used tables, razor divs apperantly. If the IDE know to add a specific class for a specific funtionality of the view, sure there is a way to modify that?

Comment: I found you an answer, and marking this as duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037365/how-to-create-custom-scaffold-templates-in-asp-net-mvc5

Comment: just hope you realize that those scaffolding templates are generated using t4 , and this is not really going to save any time if it's just for one web app and a small amount of views