# Add custom View in Adding MVC Contoller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

As you know, when we add a Controller from "MVC5 controller with views, using Entity Framework", We get Create, Delete, Details, Edit and Index view.
Now I add new View to my custom T4 for Controller.

I want to add my Custom View to that Standard Views when I add new Controller addition.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create custom scaffold templates in ASP.NET MVC5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037365/how-to-create-custom-scaffold-templates-in-asp-net-mvc5)

Comment: No, it's not. They are not same questions.